# One of the indexes running too far in a Python while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, count, index-error

I have a function that is supposed to count the number of words of each length up to and including the longest word in any given text. I'm stuck in my loop. PyCharm says:

```
sana = sanat[i].strip(",.")  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no clue why does variable I run too far (if that's what's happening here). This is in Python but this kind of problem doesn't really have anything to do with the language. I'd appreciate any help a lot.

The text is arbitrary for testing. Also, the prints are for testing.

```
    teksti = "Har du någon tanken. Om inriktningsmöjligheten i matematik."

    def sanamaarat(merkkijono):
        sanat = merkkijono.split()
        sanat.sort(key=len)
        lista = []
        lista.append(0)
        apulista = []
        apulista2 = []

        for sana in sanat:
            sana = sana.strip(",.")
            pituus = len(sana)
            apulista.append(pituus)

        joukko = list(set(apulista))
        for numero in joukko:
            apulista2.append(apulista.count(numero))
        print(sanat)
        print(apulista2)
        print(apulista)
        print(int(apulista[-1])+1)

        k = 1
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while k < int(apulista[-1]) + 1:
            sana = sanat[i].strip(",.")
            pituus = len(sana)
            if pituus == k:
                j += 1
                i += 1
            else:
                if j != 0:
                    lista.append(j)
                lista.append(0)
                k += 1

        return lista
```

And the output is here:

```
    (venv) C:\python>testailua.py
    ['i', 'du', 'Om', 'Har', 'någon', 'tanken.', 'matematik.', 'inriktningsmöjligheten']
    [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 22]
    23
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python\testailua.py", line 54, in <module>
        print(sanamaarat(teksti))
      File "C:\python\testailua.py", line 28, in sanamaarat
        sana = sanat[i].strip(",.")
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I'm trying to add the needed zeros in the right indexes of the returned list. But there's some logical error in the while loop that I cannot see.

---

Expected result is [0,1,2,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

First '0' (to index zero) because there are zero words that have length zero. First '1' (to index 1) because there is one word of length one. First '2' (to index 2) because there are two words of length two. And so on. So each index should have the number of words that have the length of that index.

---

@kederrac solved this with importing Counter from collections. That's a good answer but I'd like to know how to do it in the original way with loops because I still don't know what is wrong in my loop.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the idea of your comment. The end goal is to have a list where index 0 has the number of words of length zero, index 1 has the number of words of length one and so on.

Comment: @jonne_k I completed your question with our discussion from the chat

Comment: Thank you. I accepted & upvoted. I'm new to Python (& programming) so I didn't have any better idea than loops. I'd still like to know what is wrong with my loop, tough. So anyone is free to fix the loop version.

Comment: Oops – my briefly alluded-to solution actually was to "solve"... something not in your question. Carry on, no harm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you modify your `while` loop to check the value of the index `i` and the length of the variable `saant`:

```
print('saant lenght: ', len(sanat))
while k < int(apulista[-1]) + 1:
    print('i = ', i)
    sana = sanat[i].strip(",.")
    pituus = len(sana)
    if pituus == k:
        j += 1
        i += 1
    else:
        if j != 0:
            lista.append(j)
        lista.append(0)
        k += 1
```

the output:

```
saant lenght:  8
i =  0
i =  1
i =  1
i =  2
i =  3
i =  3
i =  4
i =  4
i =  4
i =  5
i =  5
i =  6
i =  6
i =  6
i =  6
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  7
i =  8

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-873709d80e77> in <module>
     41     return lista
     42 
---> 43 sanamaarat(teksti )

<ipython-input-61-873709d80e77> in sanamaarat(merkkijono)
     28     while k < int(apulista[-1]) + 1:
     29         print('i = ', i)
---> 30         sana = sanat[i].strip(",.")
     31         pituus = len(sana)
     32         if pituus == k:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

you will find that you are trying to access an index with the same value with the length  of your list `saanat` which it is not possible, so  you got `IndexError`

your list `saanat` has length 8 so you can access elements untill index 7, but you can see that before `IndexError` your value for `i` is 8, this cause your issue

---

to solve your problem you could use `collections.Counter` to find the frequency of words by length:

```
from collections import Counter

teksti = "Har du någon tanken. Om inriktningsmöjligheten i matematik."

def sanamaarat(merkkijono):
    count = Counter(map(len, merkkijono.split()))
    max_lenght = max(count)
    return [count.get(n, 0) for n in range(max_lenght + 1)]

print(sanamaarat(teksti))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @jonne_k check my answer now

Comment: what you are trying to do with your code?  maybe I can find a nice solution

Comment: first 0 because? first 1 because? first 2 because? will be really helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209207/discussion-between-jonne-k-and-kederrac).

Comment: @jonne_k check now my answer